# cycle plugins with dots not with numbers

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
td a { margin: 5px }
.nav { margin: 5px 0 }
#nav a, #s7 strong { margin: 0 5px; padding: 3px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none }
#nav a.activeSlide { background: #ea0 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }
#output { text-align: left; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 6000;
$(function() {
$('#s4').after('<div id="nav" class="nav">').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        pager:  '#nav'

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demos">
   <table cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <h1>Pager</h1>
        <div id="s4" class="pics">
            <img src="/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="/images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="/images/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="/images/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" />

        </div>

    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have done a little research in cycle plugin and so i try to make my own but the problem is i need that dot button instead of  1 2 or 3 etc but I am not able to find out why the 1, 2,3 are coming and from where it is coming . this is my 1st program using jquery thats y i am having little bit problem in understanding it . So plz if any one can explain me .....it will b great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the `<a>` for the "numbers" with your own images, or via CSS3 make the "dots".

Example **HTML** of the navigation generated by the above mentioned plugin:
(I created the `cycle-block`)

```
<div class="cycle-block">
    <a href="#" class="activeSlide">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
</div>
```

**and the CSS:**

```
.cycle-block a {
    background: url(../MYIMAGE.png) no-repeat scroll -305px 0 
    transparent;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 14px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

EDIT:

The numbers come from the cycle elements count, and the `pager` defined here: `pager:  '#nav'` will place the numbers in that element.

Comment: if pager :#nav place the numbers in that element , so how to replace it with dot . in this my js is making me div . can i make manually and when i click on any one it changes the pic

Comment: please can me an example

Comment: @PHP_USER1 you need to style it with CSS, no image tags involved.